# QoS software for limiting download speed on TP-LINK router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

Is there any software that I can use to limit the download speeds?

I'm using a TP-LINK router, but it doesn't have a QoS feature.

One of the people who pays to use the internet connection always downloads something whenever she connects. I want to limit the bandwidth that she is using because she's consuming too much.

Comment: Talking to her about it doesn't help? I'm adverse to technical solution for things that can be solved by social means.

Comment: Which model exactly? Also, it seems you're limited to doing this on the router, otherwise you'd need a separate firewall/proxy, or have access to her machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Howard from TP-LINK Support Force.
I suggest you upgrade the router to an 11N wireless router. It supports IP QoS.

TP-LINK Support Force
http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/
http://www.facebook.com/TPLINK

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is a policy based traffic shaper which would allow you to define rules for either the hostname she is using or the hostnames/IP addresses she is connecting to.

There are lot of commercial packet shapers that you can choose from, but if you want to play around with an open source one I came across this one in a web search ("GNU Traffic Shaper") that you could give a try to:

[**MasterShaper**](http://www.mastershaper.org/index.php/MasterShaper)

> MasterShaper is a network traffic shaper which provides a Web Interface for Quality of Servcie (QoS) functions of newer Linux 2.4- & 2.6-Kernel-Series.

I don't have direct experience with it, so take the recommendation with a cowlick sized grain of salt: It's just a pass along. You would wind up installing such a device/service in front of your router as the QOS policy manager and this would become the router for your outbound traffic.

[image]